# Vue: Access Vue component method inside rendered named slot

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, reference, vue-component, vuejs-slots

How can I access the functions of a Vue Component that is rendered inside a named slot of my component?

I have the following structure:

ParentComponent.vue

```
...
<util-component>
      <template v-slot:0>
        <child-component/>
      </template> 
      <template v-slot:1>
        //Another component, and so on
      </template> 
</util-component>
...
```

UtilComponent.vue

```
...
<div v-for="(comp, index) in components" :key="index">
  <slot :name="index" ></slot>
</div>
...
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
...
methods: {
   myFunction () { // do something } 
}
...
```

In `UtilComponent`, I want to access `ChildComponent`'s `myFunction()` (when clicking on a button, so not at mounted). I have tried using `this.$slots[0]` in UtilComponent but it's only giving me a *`VNode`* without the attributes I need (data and functions). `this.$slots[0].context` gives me the full ParentComponent. With `this.$slots[0][0].context.$children[0].$children[1]` I can actually get to ChildComponent and its functions, but this seems very roundabout (getting the parent of the rendered slot to then get the child of the child of that parent...)

Is there a better way of accessing a component('s functions) rendered inside a slot (here, `ChildComponent`) from the component which provides that slot (here, `UtilComponent`)?

Answer (score 3):

#### this.$children

You can use `this.$children` from `<util-component>` to access its slotted child components.

Imagine that each child had a method called `myMethod`:

```js
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `<div class="child">Child</div>`,
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      console.log('hi')
    }
  }
})
```

In `<util-component>`, you can loop through `this.$children`, which gives access to the slotted components, and you can access that method on each one:

```js
methods: {
  accessChildren() {
    // Loop through each child component and call its function
    this.$children.forEach(child => {
      child.myMethod();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give them a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) like :

```
<util-component>
      <template v-slot:0>
        <child-component ref="child1"/>
      </template> 
      <template v-slot:1>
        <child-component ref="child2"/>
      </template> 
</util-component>
```

then use `this.$refs.child1.myFunction()` to call the component method

Comment: Will the this.$refs.child1 be accessible from UtilComponent.vue, wouldnt it be available only in the component tht included util-component

Comment: Yes it could be accessible